# Homebridge plugin to run scripts and control brightness level

Tags: linux, script, home-automation

On Mac OS there is a plugin (homebridge-applescript-file-lightbulb) to run applescripts to e.g play music and even with argument from Siri to control "brightness" level. This makes it possible to change the music level of a speaker with Siri. Now running on Linux I can't seem to find a similar plugin to run scripts with an argument to change a light bulb's brightness (aka speaker's level).

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance